# How to determine result size in hbase?

Tags: hbase

I want to scan records in hbase from rowkey x to rowkey y, i would like to also specify a filter on these scans, I understand that we get ResultScanner object when we do an operation like this, is there a way to just get the size of the result (computed on the server side)

Typically i want something like a count() operation in mongo or sql without iterating through the resultscanner.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to request only the smallest column available which could work well if you provide the scan with an acceptable cache.

---

In case of big client-side scans, or if you want to do everything on the regionservers you can use the AggregationClient coprocessor (0.92+, must be enabled first). In case of huge scans a MapReduce job is your best friend.

Working AggregationClient example extracted from http://michaelmorello.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/row-count-hbase-aggregation-example.html :

```
public class MyAggregationClient {

    private static final byte[] TABLE_NAME = Bytes.toBytes("mytable");
    private static final byte[] CF = Bytes.toBytes("d");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        Configuration customConf = new Configuration();
        customConf.setStrings("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",
                "node0,node1,node2");
        // Increase RPC timeout, in case of a slow computation
        customConf.setLong("hbase.rpc.timeout", 600000);
        // Default is 1, set to a higher value for faster scanner.next(..)
        customConf.setLong("hbase.client.scanner.caching", 1000);
        Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create(customConf);
        AggregationClient aggregationClient = new AggregationClient(
                configuration);
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addFamily(CF);
        long rowCount = aggregationClient.rowCount(TABLE_NAME, null, scan);
        System.out.println("row count is " + rowCount);

    }
}
```

---

If you need realtime responses, you have to implement & maintain [counters](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/database-design/9781449314682/counters/id3238520).